# How to indent a part of quotation?

Tags: indentation, quotation

I have a paragraph, in a quotation, I want to add more indentation than the rest of the quotation. How can I do this?

I don't want additional space before and after the more indented paragraph.

I tried with nested `{quote}` with `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` but I don't like the extra right margin that comes with `{quote}`.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer with a definition of `myquote` as `quote` environment is defined in `article` documentclass, but without reducing the right margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newenvironment{myquote}
               {\list{}{}%In this second argument was \rightmargin\leftmargin that is unwanted for you
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}
Our first list with three items: % Corrected the ``two'' but not in the photo
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test line here that will reach the right margin inside my quotation and will go to the next line
    \item test line here that will reach the right margin inside my quotation and will go to the next line
    \begin{myquote}
    This list contains the next two items:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item test line here that will reach the right margin inside my quotation and will go to the next line
        \item test line here that will reach the right margin inside my quotation and will go to the next line
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{myquote}
    \item test line here that will reach the right margin inside my quotation and will go to the next line
    \end{enumerate}
\end{quote}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome @Max... happy TeXing!